# How to create multiple radio type that will etting seperated?

Tags: html

Im trying to create 2 different questions with radion type in HTML. But whenever i tested it, it only allows me to pick 1 even though i used  to seperate those 2 questions so it won't interact. Any help pls?

Yes or No:

Yes

No



Gender:

Male

Female

Comment: Before asking, please read [How to ask question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure There are Separate Names for each question.

For more see the difference between snippet 1 and 2.

**1 ( Working )**

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  Q1:
  <label><input type="radio" name="q1"> A1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="q1"> A2</label>
  <br>
  Q2:
  <label><input type="radio" name="q2"> A1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="q2"> A2</label>
  <span>&nbsp;</span>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**1 ( Not Working )**

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  Q1:
  <label><input type="radio" name="q1"> A1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="q1"> A2</label>
  <br>
  Q2:
  <label><input type="radio" name="q1"> A1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="q1"> A2</label>
  <span>&nbsp;</span>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**If This is not what you need pls update your question and add your code**